# Understanding Keras LSTM NN input & output for binary classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to create a simple LSTM network that would - based on the last 16 time frames - provide some output. Let's say I have a dataset with 112000 rows (measurements) and 7 columns (6 features + class). What I understand is that I have to "pack" the dataset into X number of 16 elements long batches. With 112000 rows that would mean 112000/16 = 7000 batches, therefore a numpy 3D array with shape (7000, 16, 7). Splitting this array for train and test data I get shapes:

```
xtrain.shape == (5000, 16, 6)
ytrain.shape == (5000, 16)
xtest.shape == (2000, 16, 6)
ytest.shape == (2000, 16)
```

My model looks like this:

```
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(8, input_shape=(16, 6), stateful=True, batch_size=16, name="input"));
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="relu", name="hidden1"));
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="output"));
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]);

model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, batch_size=16, epochs=10);
```

However after trying to fit the model I get this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected output to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (16,)

What I guess is wrong is that the model expects a single output per batch (so the ytrain shape should be (5000,)), instead of 16 outputs (one for every entry in a batch - (5000, 16)).

If that is the case, should I, instead of packing the data like this, create a 16 elements long batch for every output? Therefore having

```
xtrain.shape == (80000, 16, 6)
ytrain.shape == (80000,)
xtest.shape == (32000, 16, 6)
ytest.shape == (32000,)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close with the last comments of the question. Since it's a binary classification problem, you should have `1` output per input, so you need to get rid of the `16` in you `y`s and replace it for a `1`.

Besides, you need to be able to divide the train set by your batch size, so you can use `5008` for example.

In fact:

```
ytrain.shape == (5000, 1)
```

Passes the error you mention, but raises a new one:

> ValueError: In a stateful network, you should only pass inputs with a number of samples that can be divided by the batch size. Found: 5000 samples

Which is addressed by ensuring that:

```
xtrain.shape == (5008, 16, 6)
ytrain.shape == (5008, 1)
```

Comment: so, considering I have 112000 rows of data, and I want to train the LSTM on as many rows as possible, should I create 111984 "packs" of 16 rows data that I feed into the LSTM? therefore having (111984, 16, 6) as input and (111984, 1) as output... I want to train a LSTM for class on every row, but that class requires information about last 16 time frames, so for the 16th (and first) row I need information about 0-15 rows, for 17th I need information about 1-16 rows etc, therefore 112000-16 = 11984 packs of 16 element long data?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. You have `n` train samples. `n` should be divisible by the batch size, but you can fit the `n` samples and Keras will take care of the "batch" splitting. In turn, each train sample is a sequence of features. Each element of the sequence can be interpreted as a time step. And you have `f` features to describe that time step. Besides, for each train sample (consisting of a sequence of features), you have one unique `y`. This is the schema for a binary classification of a sequence.

Comment: Assume I have
    n
train samples (rows), where every sample has 3 features
    f
(columns). Features f_n0 and f_n1 are input and f_n2 is an output. This f_n2 output, however, should be based on the last 16 rows (time frames) only, nothing before that time frame. Assume 1 time frame = 1 second: the NN tries to predict the output based on what happened in the last 16 seconds.

Assuming I have 112 000 train samples (n = 112000) with 7 features (f = 7), and LSTM works with a 3D array, would be the resulting array in shape of (n-16, 16, f), or rather (n/16, 16, f) ?